# Random Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() issue

Tags: jquery, module, requirejs, anonymous

So i've got the famous requirejs error which sometimes appears sometimes doesnt.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
var i = "ViewIntro";
return $[i] = new Class({
    Extends: $.View,
    initialize: function(i, e) {
        var o = this;
        i = $(i), o.parent(i, e)
```

......ch

require.js:1

it's different var's also .

Does anyone have any idea what's causing it? Could it be connected to the amount of content on the page?